# Is PHP smart loading /etc/php/php-cli.ini?

Tags: command-line, configuration, php

I've been having issues using the PHP CLI with my current configuration in `/etc/php/php.ini` - namely: `open_basedir restriction in effect.` To combat this, I was planning on creating a separate ini file, `/etc/php/php-cli.ini` in order to call commands such as `php -c /etc/php/php-cli.ini ...`.

When creating this new file and restarting the Apache service, I called: `php --ini` and was returned with: `Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php/php-cli.ini`. When viewing a webpage containing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, it gives me this value: `Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php/php.ini`.

I had originally searched for a way to automatically use a CLI ini when using CLI and the default ini when viewing webpages, but I could not find any solutions toward that end.

Is this intended behavior or is something sinister going on?